# Elasticsearch not query according createdBy field?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I using elasticsearch, SecurityApp entity:

```
public class SecurityApp extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "app_name", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String appName;

@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "app_key", length = 20, updatable = false)
private String appKey;

@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "app_secret", length = 20, updatable = false)
private String appSecret;
// hide getter and setter
}
```

AbstractAuditingEntity entity:

```
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@CreatedBy
@Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
// @JsonIgnore
private String createdBy;

@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private ZonedDateTime createdDate = ZonedDateTime.now();

@LastModifiedBy
@Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
@JsonIgnore
private String lastModifiedBy;

@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "last_modified_date")
@JsonIgnore
private ZonedDateTime lastModifiedDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
// hide getter and setter
}
```

ElasticSearchConfiguration :

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = { JacksonConfiguration.class })
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new CustomEntityMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).build()));
}

public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
    }

    @Override
    public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
    }
}
}
```

**My Question：**
When I use the query field appName, it works. And when I use the query field createdBy, it not working! 
Why is that？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Because @JsonIgnore annotation and private permission.

When i update code like this, and **resave data**, it works.

```
@CreatedBy
@Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
// @JsonIgnore
protected String createdBy;
```

Maybe elasticsearch use json? Take reflection not available extends private fields? I don't know.

Good news. It works.

Comment: Yeah, in a JHipster application Elasticsearch stores your objects as JSON and uses Jackson to serialize/deserialize, so any fields with `@JsonIgnore` will not be indexed and not be searchable.

Comment: @geraldhumphries Why the powers of a field is private it doesn't work？

Comment: In my experience it worked just by removing JsonIgnore. Do you have a public getter and setter?

Comment: @geraldhumphries Yes，i has.  thanks a lot, I retry it.